# isSelected() всегда возвращает false

Tags: java, selenium

Изучаю selenium, и мне нужно провести проверку что CheckBox нажат, но `isSelected()` всегда возвращает `false`.  Подскажите, что не так.

```
public class CheccBox {

    static WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\Java\\SeleniumProjects\\drivers\\geckodriver.exe");

        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.get("https://www.eldorado.ru/c/televizory/f/smart-tv/");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Samsung']")).click();
        System.out.println( driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Samsung']")).isSelected());
    }
}
```

Comment: а нажимается? Добавь паузу в полсекунды перед проверкой

Comment: да нажимается...

Comment: а по поводу паузы что?

Comment: пауза не помогает, скорее всего не правильно написан xPash нужно делать переход на предков этого узла

Comment: Сходил на страницу. Думаю, что проблема в том, что находится не чекбокс, а само слово samsung и нажимается тоже само слово и проверяется тоже само слово, которое понятное дело не может быть селектед. Нажимать на слово можно (это работает), но проверять надо чекбокс.

Answer (score 1):

как говориться в документации:
Is Element Selected
This method determines if the referenced Element is Selected or not. This method is widely used on Check boxes, radio buttons, input elements, and option elements.

Вы же, пытаетесь обратиться к ссылке "а" по тексту а не к чекбоксу.

Вам нужно найти локатор именно чекбокса.